# readline createInterface is not a function when run client-side

Tags: javascript, readline

## Issue using readline

### Setup

- I am trying to use 'readline' package in a client-side dev setup, using watchify targeting a bundle.js file and python to create a server.
- The module works fine with node.js but fails to work in this dev setup.

### "TypeError: readline.createInterface is not a function"

```js
const rl = require("readline")
// const readline = rl.default
const ui = rl.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
```

I found one solution [in another stackoverflow post for readline-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71814859/typeerror-readline-createinterface-is-not-a-function), (and in an issue log for the repo) claiming the problem could be avoided by explicitly targeting the default entry point (?). Doesn't work for me here however!

Comment: Yes of course this doesn't work. There is no `process.stdin/out` in a browser environment. What do you expect to read from?

Comment: well I was gonna use it in tandem with a 'terminal' package of some kind.

Comment: How would you go about that?

Comment: Unless that "terminal package" uses a node.js stream, you don't use `readline` at all. Please link the docs of the package you want to use, it should demonstrate how to read lines of input from it.